# concatenate values in SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, insert, concatenation

I have a stored procedure on SQL Server 2008 that copies certain values from one table to another, I need to take 3 of the values and make them into one value in the second (copy to) Table.

```
INSERT INTO copyto (FIELD_ONE, FIELD_TWO, FIELD_THREE, 
            OTHER_DATA1, OTHER_DATA2, OTHER_DATA3, 
            )
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(OTHER_DATA1)), LTRIM(RTRIM(OTHER_DATA2)),
       LTRIM(RTRIM(OTHER_DATA3)),LTRIM(RTRIM(FIELD_ONE)),
       LTRIM(RTRIM(FIELD_TWO)), LTRIM(RTRIM(FIELD_THREE))
       FROM copyfrom
```

Within the above example (which is code extracted from the stored procedure) I need to concatenate fields 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: you want to concatnate fields 1,2,and 3: Where do you want to insert them?

Comment: I want to insert them as one filed in the COPYTO table instead of inserting filed1, filed2, filed3 seperately

Comment: I'm with Sherif here, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: please try and realise I cannot put the actual code here due to contractural obligations I QUICKLY typed up and representation of the code and the below answer resolved the issue thanks for your comments and answers, I am waiting the manadatory 6 minutes to accept the answer provided. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply concatenate them as you would in any/most other programming languages:

```
select LTRIM(RTRIM(FIELD_ONE)) + LTRIM(RTRIM(FIELD_TWO)) + LTRIM(RTRIM(FIELD_THREE))
FROM copyfrom
```

This will "return" one column.

Answer (score 3):

Note that concatenating fields with '+' will return no results if at least one of your fields happen to be NULL. Use `ISNULL(myfield,'')` or `COALESCE(myfield,'')` as pre-checks on each